# client.channels.get is not a function in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Help me, I'm trying to create a discord bot, and I want send a message in a specific channel but it dosen't work.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client =  new Discord.Client();

client.login("MyToken")

client.on("ready", function(){
   client.channels.get("IdChannel").send("Hi!");
})
```

This error appears:

```
TypeError: client.channels.get is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong? Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using **Discord.js V12**. This particular version changed [client.channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client?scrollTo=channels) from a [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Collection) into a [ChannelManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/ChannelManager). Where `.get` is replaced with `.fetch`.

So to fix your issue, all you need todo is use

```js
client.channels.fetch("IdChannel").send("Hi!");
```

instead of

```js
client.channels.get("IdChannel").send("Hi!");
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand, can yuo write me the all code? Thank you so much

Comment: instead of `.get` do `.fetch` as seen above.